# How to send form data to a Spring controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Sudoku board generated with thymeleaf and I want to send all the tile values as a double array to a Spring controller or as a String.

```
<form class="box" id="sudokuBoard">
        <table>
            <tr th:each="row: ${board}">
                <td th:each="value: ${row}">
                    <div th:switch="${value}">
                        <input th:case="0" style="width:30px;height:30px;text-align:center" type = "text" maxlength="1" value="0">
                        <input th:case="*" style="width:30px;height:30px;text-align:center;background-color:lightgreen" type = "text" th:value="${value}" readonly>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit"> Check Solution </input>
    </form>
```

I've tried to use the `serialize()` function but it doesn't send anything or I'm doing something wrong.

```
<script>
        $("#sudokuBoard").submit(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

            var form = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/sudoku",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    console.log("data sent");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sudoku", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String checkBoardStatus(@RequestBody String jsonString){
        System.out.println("json string: " + jsonString);
        return "sudoku";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example, where success will be your callback method

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(result) {},
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sudoku", method = RequestMethod.POST)
String checkBoardStatus(Map<String,Object> params){
    System.out.println("Request Params: " + params);
    return "sudoku";
}
```

User above code.. Try to use a DTO class to map request body instead of Map and do not use @RequestBody annotation

Comment: Tried but still empty, for some reason the data on the `<input>` fields is not being passed with the form.

Comment: You have to declare  name attributes on each input field

Comment: This was the problem, declared names for inputs and now the data is being sent to the controller.